# Laravel постоянно выполнять сложный скрипт

Tags: laravel, websocket

вопрос больше в том, как лучше поступить. Я делаю игру про майнинг. Пользователь собирает майнинг ферму, а потом ферма работает, нагревается и ТД. То есть на сервере должен постоянно работать скрипт, который будет в зависимости от комплектующих считать производительность, температуру, какие-то поломки и ТД. И все это для многих ферм многих пользователей.

> То есть скрипт довольно ресурсоемкий.

1. Как мне выполнять этот скрипт? Нужно выполнять его для всех пользователей хотя бы раз в минуту, чтобы пользователь видел, что его ферма работала.

Может как-то через очереди? Или schedule?

2. К тому же нужно выводить новые значения на страницу - ферма нагрелась - пользователь должен это видеть.

Может быть использовать веьсокеты? Я видел laravel websocket by beyond code. Вроде бы это как раз то, что нужно и без nodejs.

Если для сокетов использовать nodejs, то будет проблематично связать году и ларавель. По крайней мере я так думаю.

**Итак, ваши идеи**
Надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться [планированием задач](https://laravel.com/docs/scheduling).

Метод `everyMinute` будет запускать задачу каждую минуту:

```php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            // Cчитать производительность, температуру, какие-то поломки
        })->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Comment: А как доносить изменения до пользователя? И насколько целесообразно каждую минуту запускать сложный скрипт, скажем, для   100 пользователей, у каждого из которых 3 фермы?

Comment: например ajax-ом забирать раз в n-секунд состояние фермы...